# java - why is this recursive method exceeding what I expected

Tags: java, recursion

Doing a very simple program to test out recursion. The program prints something until the number is not greater than 0.

```
public class TestIt {

public static void print(int f){
    while(f>0){
        System.out.println("Not today");
        f--;
        print(f);
    }
  }
}
```

the code above is called from the main program like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestIt.print(2);
}
```

Maybe I'm finally losing my mind, but the amount of times the program prints is exceeding what I expected. If I send 3 to the method then the program prints 7 times. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: "the program prints is exceeding what I expected" - What did you expect?

Comment: was expecting it to print twice for 2 and not 7 times for 3. it's been answered now though. can't believe i didn't catch that myself.

Comment: A use of recursive methods is to get rid of `loops`, so having a `while` loop should sound alarm bells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because everytime the call comes off the stack, `f` is still what it was originally, and then it continues with the `while` loop. So for `2`:

```
while(f>0){
    System.out.println("Not today");
    f--;
    print(f);
}
```

- First run, subtracts from 2, results in one. (Print count = 1) Resursive call:

  - Subtracts again, 0, recursive call: (Print count 2)

    - While loop is never entered. returns:
  - 0, while loop is not executed, reuturns:
- While loop is run again, recursive call: (print count = 3)

  - Passes zero, while loop not entered, return
- While loop terminated, exit method

For `2` it prints three times, but this grows for every number passed in. To fix this do:

```
if(f>0){
    System.out.println("Not today");
    f--;
    print(f);
}
```

Remember recursion usually is to avoid loops, so if you find yourself using both, this is usually a red flag

Answer (score 5):

Because you did wrong

```
while(f>0){
    System.out.println("Not today");
    f--;
    print(f);
}
```

you are calling the method `print` f in the loop times
and as it is recursive it will be called f-1 times recursivelly

so it will b f fatorial times

remove the `while` loop and will work as you want

Comment: Saw this one first and immediately changed it to an if statement. Thanks for your help.